# google map loads partially - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, google-maps

[Google map loads like this on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlobZ.jpg)

My site is wordpress and google map loads partially.(routes loading, backgroun map isn't, please look at the attached image) why is this happening? Is this causing from my code or is it google map bug? There're no errors on the console either.

```
<!---------------------------- Map ------------------------->

  <?php if (!empty($arr)) { ?>
      <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<my_key>"
              type="text/javascript"></script>
      <div class="container map-container">
          <div class="overlay" onClick="style.pointerEvents='none'"></div>
          <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 600px;"></div>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript">


          var locations = <?php echo json_encode($arr); ?>;

          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              scrollwheel: false,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          });

          var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
          var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

          var marker, i;


          for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
              marker = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]);

              new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: marker,
                  map: map
              });

              bounds.extend(marker);

              google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                  return function () {
                      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                      infowindow.open(map, marker);
                  }
              })(marker, i));
          }


          var userCoorPath = [];
          for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
              userCoorPath[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]);
          }

          var userCoordinate = new google.maps.Polyline({
              path: userCoorPath,
              strokeColor: "#000000",
              strokeOpacity: 1,
              strokeWeight: 2
          });
          userCoordinate.setMap(map);

          map.fitBounds(bounds);
      </script>
  <?php } ?>

  <!---------------------------- EndMap ------------------------->
```

Comment: the map div is not immediatly visible in page loading ? the map div is showed  in a separated  tab showed  after the page loading?

Comment: inspect the map div and check if css is implementing on it by google maps or try to place map div outside container class.Sometimes due to slow internet speed,i also faced this type of issues.

Comment: I tried inspecting and there's nothing that affect. I even tried temporally deleting my css folder. Still only gray box and lines between cities shows.